# How to get start and end date value from Sat Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I try to get start date and end date value using change function in Sat date picker. But it's not working properly.

```
 <input
        [(ngModel)]="dateRanger"
        matInput
        name="dateRange"
        placeholder="Select Date Range"
        [satDatepicker]="picker"
        [max]="tomorrow"
      />
      <sat-datepicker
        required
        disabled="false"
        #picker
        [rangeMode]="true"
        (dateChange)="dateChanged($event)"
      >
      </sat-datepicker>
```

> Event Function as below

```
    dateChanged(event) {
       console.log('event', event);
    }
```

How can i get date range value in sat date picker

Comment: your dateRanger variable (the variable you use in ngModel) is an object with two properties: begin and end, so simple you has `dateRanger.begin` and `dateRanger.end`

Comment: Is there have change function when selecting date range ??

Comment: if you need make "something" you has two options, use (dateChange) or use [(ngModel)] in the way `<input [ngModel]="dateRange" (ngModelChange)="dateRange=$event;yourFunction($event)">` If the only you need is has the value, e.g. in a form you need the two values it's not necesary. [(ngModel)] is two ways binding